# Sending multiple mysql instructions through a jdbc connection in Google Script

Tags: mysql, jdbc, google-apps-script, google-cloud-sql

I'd like to send several queries to the Google Cloud SQL database from Google Apps Script in one row. For example :

```
insert into table_name (field_name) values ("prout");
select last_insert_id()
```

but for some reason I can't get it to work. Is the API limited to one query per time ? It is a pain because sending a query takes time. It would be a lot more efficient to be able to send several things at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you may not be able to send multiple queries at the same time is because each statement will have a different return value. For example, an "insert" statement will give you an integer indicating how many rows were affected (hopefully 1!). A "select" statement will return to you a set of objects.

You can do batch commands using [addBatch](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_jdbcpreparedstatement#addBatch), but they must all be of the same type of query (for example, a lot of "insert"s).